# Python and Kivy - keyboard on_key_down triggering twice and behaves weird

Tags: python, kivy

I have a simple kivy application in python with a ScreenManager and a Screen called MainWindow.
I have my main.kv file in which i only have a FloatLayout with id mainLayout
In my MainWindow class i have this simple code:

```py
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.core.window import Window


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class MainWindow(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super().__init__(**kw)
        self.keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(None, self)
        self.keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self.key_pressed)
        self.quit_requests = 0

    def key_pressed(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        print(keycode[1])
        key = keycode[1]

        if key == "q":
            print("Pressed q")
            self.quit_requests += 1
            if self.quit_requests == 3:
                exit()
        else:
            print("Pressed something")
            self.quit_requests = 0
        print("End of method")


kv = Builder.load_file("GUI/main.kv")


class MainApp(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):
        self.title = "Neural Network"
        return kv
```

The main.kv file:

```
WindowManager:
    MainWindow:

:
    FloatLayout:
        size_hint: None, None
        id: mainLayout
        pos: 0, 0
        width: root.width
        height: root.height
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: .1, .1, .1, 1
            Rectangle:
                pos: mainLayout.pos
                size: mainLayout.size
```

Then from the main script i call

```py
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '400')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '400')
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', True)
Config.set('kivy', 'exit_on_escape', '0')
Config.set('input', 'mouse', 'mouse,multitouch_on_demand')
Config.set('graphics', 'window_state', 'normal')
Config.set('graphics', 'fullscreen', False)
Config.write()

MainApp().run()
```

What i am trying to achieve here, is that when the user presses a keyboard button i do some stuff, and when a user presses the "q" key 3 times in a row i close the application.
What happens with the code above is the following:
every time i press a button, i see the respective printed messages **twice**, so if i press "e" **once** in the console i see:

```
e
Pressed something
End of method
e
Pressed something
End of method
```

If i press q i see:

```
q
Pressed q
End of method
q
Pressed q
End of method
```

At this point i assume that the method "key_pressed" is called twice for some reason, and that's why i see double the prints, but at the same time, if this is the case, i should also assume that the application should quit after i pressed "q" just 2 times, but this is not the case. The application quits correctly just after 3 times i pressed "q". 
Why, and how to prevent this double method call from kivy?

Comment: Can you post a minimal runnable example?

Comment: I edited the question, there is not much more, the code is pretty simple. Let me know if that's enough

Comment: "Minimal runnable example" means the example should run without further modification. Please post the main script, and its relationship with the rest of the code.

Comment: That is literally all the code there is for running the application. I have the main.py script with those Config calls and MainApp.run(), and the other file Mainwindow.py with those 3 classes, that calls the file main.kv. Other than the imports of the main file that depend on the project structure.I am pretty new here, if that is not what you usually do please be more specific.

Comment: That's the problem, you haven't posted "literally all" the code at all. That means readers can't just run it to debug, and errors that may be related to your file structure will be missed. Your problem could even be the latter, if you're somehow accidentally loading a kv file twice.

Comment: So basically you are telling me to upload a zip somewhere containing all my project and linking it in the question?

Comment: No, post a minimal runnable example, i.e. a small amount of code that can be run without extra modification and is as short as possible. It doesn't have to be your full project (in fact generally it shouldn't be), a smaller example that is ideal. What you posted is very close, if you add in the few missing bits. Linking an actual project is worse because that's more effort to look at.